# Using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo is it possible to work out which window mouse pointer is over?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, nswindow, nsevent

Using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo is it possible to work out if the mouse pointer is over any of the windows listed?

The problem I'm having is that the windows bounds provided by CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo are top left origin based. But something like...

```
NSPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
```

is bottom left origin based.

Comment: `[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]` will tell you the height of the main screen, from which you can subtract `mouseLoc.y`.  Of course, it gets more complicated if more than one screen is being used...

Comment: @SmilinBrian Is there a way to know which screen a window CGWindow is on, so this method could be extended to support multiple screens?